# Count the number of pullback

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to code in pinescript the number of pullbacks after ema 20 crossing ema 50.
I could able to plot the pull back but unable to figure out to reset the counter and plot the counter after ema 20 crossing 50.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Show us what you have tried so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `var` variable to track/reset the counter.

As long as you have the condition when to start tracking pull back and when that pull back is considered to be ended.

PS: For pullback, I'd suggest to identify candle pivot instead of crossover, as ema crossover is a lagging indicator and may cause inaccurate count.